# Writing the Piecewise Function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

I have to solve each equation and verify my solution graphically... but first, I would like to create the piecewise for **$|x^2 - 2x + 2| = 3x - 4$** to have a reference to know if my solution is extraneous.

I know that I would need to find the solutions for **$x^2 - 2x + 2$** (Case 1) and **$-x^2 + 2x - 2$** (Case 2), and since it's not factorable, I used the quadratic formula:

**[Case 1]**
\begin{align*}
x & = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{(-2)^2 - 4(1)(2)}}{2}\\
x & = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4 - 8}}{2}
\end{align*}
This is where I got stuck... I'd get $-12$ in the square root which isn't correct, but my math and variables were right. I don't understand what I did wrong?

*[edit]* Same thing happened when solving **Case 2**, where I got $-4$ in the square root.

Comment: You don't need to solve $x^2-2x+2=0$.  You need to solve the equation you are given, which has something on the right hand side.

Comment: What you did wrong was assume that $x^2 - 2x + 2 = x^2 - 2x + 1 + 1 = (x - 1)^2 + 1$ could take negative values.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^2-2x+2=(x-1)^2+1$ is always positive, so you can just remove the absolute value bars.  Then
$$x^2-2x+2=3x-4\\x^2-5x+6=0\\(x-2)(x-3)=0\\x=2,3$$

Comment: How did you get $(x -1)^2 + 1$?

Comment: You can expand the square to verify it.  I just noted that $(x-1)^2$ has the same quadratic and linear terms as we are working with, so split off the $+1$ to complete the square.